# momentjs time conversion not taking care of daylight saving

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert PST (America/phoenix) to IST (Asia/Calcutta) and GMT by the use of moment Timezone Library, But the conversion is wrong as it is not taking care of daylight saving time. Please check the implementation:

http://codepen.io/prashantsrs/pen/pEXYOX

```
var phoenix_time=moment.tz("2016-11-15 07:00:00","America/Phoenix");
var india_time=phoenix_time.clone().tz("Asia/Calcutta");
document.write('indian time is '+india_time.format()+'<br>');
var gmt_time=phoenix_time.clone().tz("Etc/UTC");
document.write('gmat time is '+gmt_time.format());`
```

The output should be 20:30 for IST but the output is 19:30. Similarly same is the problem with gmt

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: The result is correct according to this -  http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20161115T07&p1=197&p2=54&p3=769

Comment: The result is wrong. Check here: - https://savvytime.com/converter/pst-to-ist/nov-15-2016/7-00am